# How can I get maven to just print pom coordinates?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I would like maven to parse a pom file for me and just print out the coordinates of the generated artifact(s).  Maven is obviously parsing this info, I just want to know how to get it printed and then have maven stop.  I want to use this in some shell scripting, and parsing the pom seems onerous to do in bash - especially with all the inheritance implications and dependency coordinates listed throughout.  I don't want any building to occur since I may only have the POM, not the source files.

The best way I've found so far is to parse the output of this:

```
mvn -N dependency:tree
```

This seems a bit heavy-weight since it parses ALL dependencies.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean groupId, artifactId and version?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a small java programm which exactly does this like the following:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;

public class PomRead {

    public String getPomVersion(Model model) {
        String result = model.getVersion();
        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The artifact does not define a version.");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Model readModel(InputStream is) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        MavenXpp3Reader model = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model read = model.read(is);
        return read;
    }

    public Model readModel(File file) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        return readModel(fis);
    }

    public String getVersionFromPom(File pomFile) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        Model model = readModel(pomFile);
        return getPomVersion(model);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Invalid number of arguments.");
            System.err.println("");
            System.err.println("usage: pom.xml");
            return;
        }

        String pom = args[0];
        File pomFile = new File(pom);
        if (!pomFile.exists() || !pomFile.isFile() || !pomFile.canRead()) {
            System.err.println("File " + pomFile + " can not be accessed or does not exist.");
            return;
        }

        PomRead pomRead = new PomRead();
        try {
            String version = pomRead.getVersionFromPom(pomFile);
            System.out.println(version);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

You need of course the following pom.xml for that small program where a single dependency is important:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

May be it should be added such a goal to one of the numerous maven plugins to support such a thing. The above prints out the version only but can simply be enhanced to print also groupId and artifactId.

Comment: To be clear, I really need the full coordinates.  I completely agree about adding this to a common plugin (maven-dependency-plugin maybe).

Comment: So it shouldn't be a problem to add them to the above snippet.